# Azure Synapse analytics temporary table DDL

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Is there any way we can view the definition of a temporary table in Azure Synapse.

I tried in sys.tables but it is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Temporal table in Azure Synapse is limited to session only.They are only visible to the session in which they are created and automatically dropped when session logs off.

Comment: Thanks Rahul.. Yes, I got that.. Is there a way to see the table definition of a temporary table.

Comment: @Jegatheesan Global temporary tables are not supported in Azure Synapse. Also existence of temporary tables are limited to current session only.It means that you can create temporary tables with same name in each session of synapse. Also you CANNOT check its schema from system objects.

My question is : If you are creating a temporary table from a procedure, then you can easily check its schema by looking into code of that proc. Situation might get worse if you don't have the access rights to view code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Rahul. If we are creating the temp table using create table statement, then we could see that.I am using CTAS for creating a temporary tables by joining more tables. Want to know the definition of temporary table rather than going to each and every table used in joins. Please suggest any solution for this.